# Python chunk array on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create chunks out of an array under certain conditions.
Lets say I want all chunks that are not null.

```
array = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
# array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])

out = chunks(array)
# array([[0,[1]],[4,[1, 1]],[8,[1]])
```

Now i know that the first chunk starts a index 0 and contains [1]

```
0: 0 -> [1]
1: 4 -> [1,1]
2: 8 -> [1]
```

It does not have to look like this, 
but I did not know any better.
So far, I have done it with for loops.
But every time I look my code, it depresses me :).

Is There any better way (Numpy magic)?

Comment: what about np.where?

Comment: I thought about it but i ended up with loops, because np.where(x>1) returns all indices where x>1 and i must check if they belong together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one on for size :)

Using `np.where` to filter, `np.diff` and `np.split` for grouping consecutive indexes.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
idx_matching_1 = np.where(array == 1)[0]
consecutive_groups_of_1_idx = np.split(idx_matching_1, np.where(np.diff(idx_matching_1) != 1)[0] + 1)
print(consecutive_groups_of_1_idx)


[array([0]), array([4, 5]), array([8])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way -

```
def group_elems(a, nullval=0):
    mask = a!=nullval
    mask_ext = np.r_[False, mask, False]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask_ext[1:] != mask_ext[:-1])
    cut_idx = (idx[1::2] - idx[::2]).cumsum()
    return dict(zip(idx[::2], np.split(a[mask], cut_idx[:-1])))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [62]: a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])

In [63]: group_elems(a, nullval=0)
Out[63]: {0: array([1]), 4: array([1, 1]), 8: array([1])}

In [64]: a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0])

In [65]: group_elems(a, nullval=0)
Out[65]: {0: array([1]), 4: array([2, 3]), 8: array([4])}
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i am asking for, but the other answer fits better